Condition for symmetry of $A'(x)x$
I have a differentiable matrix function $x\in\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto A(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ where $A(x)$ is symmetric for every $x$. Since $A$ is differentiable the Jacobian $A'$ exists:
$$(A'(x))^i_{jk} = \frac{\partial A^i_j(x)}{\partial x^k}.$$
I now define a matrix function $B:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as follows $B(x) = A'(x)x$:
$$(B(x))^i_k = \sum_{j=1}^n (A'(x))^i_{jk} x^j = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial A^i_j(x)}{\partial x^k} x^j.$$
Then $B(x)$ is a symmetric matrix iff:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial A^i_j(x)}{\partial x^k} x^j = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial A^k_j(x)}{\partial x^i} x^j.$$
A sufficient condition (thanks to Ted Black's answer for pointing out that the condition is not necessary) for the above to hold for any $x$ is:
$$\frac{\partial A^i_j(x)}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial A^k_j(x)}{\partial x^i}.$$
The above would be true for instance if the $n$ vector fields $A_1(x),\ldots, A_n(x)$ (these vectors are the columns of the matrix) are gradient fields. That is, there exist functions $g_1,\ldots,g_n : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $A_j = \nabla g_j$.
Can I in any way leverage the symmetry of $A$ and some additional sufficient condition in order to get an implication for the above? Or should I expect that the symmetry of $A$ gives me nothing additional regarding the above?
This arose from trying to come up with a sufficient condition for the symmetry of the Jacobian $J_f$ of the vector function $f(x) = A(x) x$. The Jacobian being $J_f(x) = A(x) + A'(x)x$. If I want the latter to be symmetric then I need that $A'(x)x$ is symmetric. I am not sure whether the symmetry of $A$ plays any role whatsoever (in the general case) for the symmetry of $A'(x)x$. The end goal is really Newton-Raphson, and if $J_f(x)$ is symmetric I need to solve a symmetric system, while if $J_f(x)$ is non-symmetric I need to solve a non-symmetric system (which is a bit more work with iterative solvers).

@TedBlack The thing is though that $B^i_k = T^i_{,jk}$ and not $B^i_j = T^i_{,jk}$.

In $$\frac{\partial A^i_j(x)}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial A^k_j(x)}{\partial x^i}.$$ index $i$ starts as contravariant in the l.h.s. and ends up covariant in the r.h.s. ; the opposite is true for $k$. I cannot follow...

@TedBlack Covariant/contravariant doesn't matter here, this is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard dot product, so your metric tensor is the identity and you can switch with just a transposition. The identity that I have written is equivalent to saying $(A'(x)x) = (A'(x)x)^T$ for any $x$. The reason I have $i$ up is to emphasize that this is a row index in expressions such as  $(A'(x)x)^i_k = \sum_j \partial_{x^k}A^i_j x^j$, since $A'(x)x$ is a linear map (i.e. $(1,1)$ tensor) that would consume another vector, i.e., $(A'(x)x)y = B(x)y$.

If upstairs means row index then when you write $\partial {A^i}_j / \partial x^k$  this is an object with one row index and two column indices. How would you define this object and its contraction with $x^j$?

@TedBlack It's as defined in the question $$B(x)^i_k = (A'(x)x)^i_k = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial A^i_j(x)}{\partial x^k} x^j$$
I don't think there's anything ambiguous with the way I defined things in the question. As mentioned, this is motivated by differentiating $f(x) = A(x)x$ which gives you precisely this form of $A'(x)x$ where you contract along the first column index, i.e., $J_f(x) = A(x) + A'(x)x$ with my definition of $A'(x)x$.

The reason I am asking these questions is because according to your definitions if I start with $B^i_k=\frac{\partial A^i_j}{\partial x^k} x^j$ then to test symmetry I write $B^k_i=\frac{\partial A^k_j}{\partial x^i} x^j$ which after I use the symmetry of $A$ becomes $B^k_i=\frac{\partial A^j_k}{\partial x^i} x^j$ which is meaningless.

@TedBlack $B$ is symmetric iff $B^i_k = B^k_i$. In other words:
$$B^i_k = \sum_j \frac{\partial A^i_j}{\partial x^k} x^j = \sum_j \frac{\partial A^k_j}{\partial x^i} x^j = B^k_i$$
If you wish for this to hold for any $x$, it is sufficient that
$$\frac{\partial A^i_j(x)}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial A^k_j(x)}{\partial x^i}.$$

@TedBlack $$B^k_i = \sum_j \frac{\partial A^k_j}{\partial x^i} x^j \stackrel{A=A^T}{=} \sum_j \frac{\partial (A^T)^k_j}{\partial x^i} x^j = \sum_j \frac{\partial A^j_k}{\partial x^i} x^j$$
So no, it is not meaningless, despite of the fact that you have a sum over two upper indices, the above expression is still perfectly well-defined. If it bothers you, you can lower the index of $x$, but that's not the point. I am not sure how using the symmetry if $A$ helps here though.

This is not an answer; it is  a sketch that may point to an answer. It is too long to fit into a comment.
Start with your definition
$$
f^i(x)={A^i}_j(x)x^j.
$$
Then
$$ 
\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\pdv{f^i}{x^k}=\pdv{{A^i}_j}{x^k}x^j+{A^i}_k.
$$
Define
$$
{A^i}_j=x^ix^{j'}g_{jj'}.
$$
$g:V \times V\to \mathbb{F}$ is the bilinear form that defines the inner product in a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$; for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an orthonormal basis, $g_{jj'}=\delta_{jj'}$. Then
$$
{A_j}^i={A^{i'}}_{j'}g_{i'j}g^{j'i}=x^{i'}x^{j''}g_{j'j''}g_{i'j}g^{j'i}=x^{i'}x^{j''}\delta^i_{j''}g_{i'j}=x^ix^{i'}g_{i'j}={A^i}_j
$$
and $A$ is symmetric.
In this case
$$\def\d{{\sf d}}
\d{A^i}_j=(\d x^i)x^{j'}g_{jj'}+x^i(\d x^{j'})g_{jj'}=\delta^i_k(\d x^k)x^{j'}g_{jj'}+x^i\delta^{j'}_k(\d x^k)g_{jj'}=(\delta^i_kx^{j'}g_{jj'}+x^i\delta^{j'}_kg_{jj'})\d x^k=(\delta^i_kx^{j'}g_{jj'}+x^ig_{jk}) \d x^k
$$
and
$$
\pdv{{A^i}_j}{x^k}=\delta^i_kx^{j'}g_{jj'}+x^ig_{jk}.
$$
We can therefore write
$$
\pdv{f^i}{x^k}=\pdv{{A^i}_j}{x^k}x^j+{A^i}_k=(\delta^i_kx^{j'}g_{jj'}+x^ig_{jk})x^j+{A^i}_k=\delta^i_kx^{j'}g_{jj'}x^j+x^ix^jg_{jk}+{A^i}_k=g(x,x)\delta^i_k +
2{A^i}_k.
$$
Since $\pdv{f^i}{x^k}$ is a second-order mixed tensor ${T^i}_k$
$$
{T^i}_k=g(x,x)\delta^i_k +
2{A^i}_k=g(x,x)\delta^i_k +
2{A_k}^i={T_k}^i
$$
in this case the Jacobian matrix  is symmetric. However note that $\pdv{{A^i}_j}{x^k}$ is not symmetric w.r.t. indices $i,k$. Although $\delta^i_kx^{j'}g_{jj'}$ is symmetric w.r.t. these indices, $x^ig_{jk}$ is not.

I don't get why you defined $A^i_j = x^i x^j g_{jj'} = x_jx^i$, i.e., $A= xx^T$. This doesn't hold for my question nor does it hold in general. Also I think I understood what you were confused about, $A^i_j=A^j_i$ is an equality as numbers which is just the definition of symmetry. One could write $C= A^T$ and $A^i_j = C^i_j (= A^j_i)$ if $A^i_j = A^j_i$ bothers you.

It is clear that if $A=xx^T$ then $f(x) = Ax = |x|^2x$ has a symmetric Jacobian because $J_f(x) = |x|^2I + 2|x| xx^T$, but $A=xx^T$ simply doesn't hold here.

Note also that all the metric tensor juggling is unnecessary. I am in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the array of numbers $(A(x))^i_j$ IS the element $A(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. You shouldn't think of coordinates here (despite of the fact that $A$ is also the coordinate representation of $A$ in the standadd basis $A=[A]^E_E$). I think I confused you by using upper and lower indices. I should have probably just written $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$ and so on.

This very simple example was done to show that  the Jacobian matrix can be symmetric even though $\partial{{A^i}_j}/\partial{x^k}$ is not symmetric w.r.t. indices $i,k$.

You are right $$\partial x^i x_j /\partial x^k = \delta^{ik} x_j + x^i \delta_{jk} \ne \delta^{ki} x_j + x^k \delta_{ji} = \partial x^k x_j / \partial x^i$$
I get what you mean, I wrote iff for the symmetry, but I should have written if, since $\partial A^i_j /\partial x^k = \partial A^k_j /\partial x^i$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition. This is a good catch, I upvoted your answer.

@lightxbulb thanks for the upvote; I would be interested to see a reference that shows why we can write $\partial x^i x_j / \partial x^k=\delta^{ik}x_j+x^i \delta_{jk}$.

Suppose you have a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The matrix $xx^T$ has entries $x^ix_j$. Now differentiate each entry w.r.t. $x^k$, you get exactly the above. I am not certain but I think it's the upper/lower indexing that throws you off. As I mentioned, since I am in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the indexing is actually irrelevant and is just to keep track of what's a row or columns, but I could have just as easily written $A^i_j = (xx^T)^i_j = x_i x_j$ and the derivative would have been $$\frac{\partial A^i_j}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial x_i x_j}{\partial x_k} = \delta_{ik}x_j + x_i \delta_{jk}.$$

The issue with the latter notation is that it's not directly obviously that $i$ is a row index from the expression on the right. E.g. in all of basic linear algebra people write $A_{ij}$ even when they mean $A^i_j$ because in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ it doesn't really matter since your matrix and its coordinate representation in the standard basis are one and the same. This is of course not true in other vector spaces.

I am just trying to understand this. As you point out we can write $xx^\top$ as $x^ix_j$; upstairs is row index, downstairs is column index. Now we take the partial derivative $\partial (x^ix_j)/\partial x^k$. Before we evaluate the expression is  $k$ a row index or a column index?

You can write $xx^T$ just as well in the form $(xx^T)_{ij} = x_i x_j$ (which is what would be done in basic linear algebra courses), you'll just have to remember which index corresponds to the row and which corresponds to the column, the upper/lower here helps with not having to remember the latter. When you take the derivative it is irrelevant whether $k$ is a row or column index, at least w.r.t. derivative of a single entry, it only matters regarding how you arrange your resulting derivatives later on. I take the convention that the Jacobian $J_f$ of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$

is a row-vector, i.e., $\partial f/\partial x^k$ produces a row-vector $J_f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$, i.e., $(J_f(x))k = \partial f/\partial x^k$. With this convention if $A^i_j = x^i x_j$ then $\partial A^i_j /\partial x^k = \partial x^i x_j /\partial x^k = B^i{jk}$, where $B^i_{jk} = \delta^i_k x_j + x^i \delta_{jk}$. The opposite convention is also a thing in matrix calculus however. For the purposes of this problem the only thing that matters is that $i$ is an upper index and comes first in order to emphasize this is the output, the rest you can switch if you like.

My intuition would be that the cases where $\sum_j \partial A^i_j / \partial x^k x^j = \sum_j \partial A^k_j / \partial x^i x^j$ but $\partial A^i_j / \partial x^k \ne \partial A^k_j / \partial x^i$ are rare. For my specific problem I have been manually differentiating a quite complicated function for a few days already (maple won't really save me - the function is written in code, and translating it will take just as much effort). I was hoping that symmetry could save some of those computation, but I kind of gave up on that. I agree that for manifolds the indices would matter much more though
